# how to use two spring security <intercept-url tags with similar url patterns?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have following sitution

Everything under /drug is secure I dont want the users to be able to view any under /drug so I have this rule in my spring security config.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/drug/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_DRUG')" />
```

But when users hit /drug I want to be able to show an access denied page with a message on how they can buy this section or module and I have to show the access denied message under the same url i.e. /drug/access-denied

so I added another rule in spring security config

```
<intercept-url pattern="/drug/access-denied" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
```

but spring security seems to be considering just one of them which is first one, changing order didnt make any difference. and the url has to be /drug/access-denied

any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

See below configuration and try to make similar in yours.
First of all I am not getting why you wrote

```
<intercept-url pattern="/drug/access-denied" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
```

what is there in access denied page that you want only authenticated users to view that page.

with your configuration, when it finds to show the access denied page at that time you mentioned it as isAuthenticated() then again if user is not logged in and directly tries to access the page it will send user to login page unstead of access denied page.

I think it should be,

```
<intercept-url pattern="/drug/access-denied" access="permitAll"/>
```

then write,

```
<intercept-url pattern="/drug/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_DRUG')" />
```

See below

```
<security:form-login  login-page="/login.jsp"
    default-target-url="/drug/home"  authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />

<security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp"
    access="permitAll" />


<security:intercept-url pattern="/accessDenied.jsp"
    access="permitAll" />


    <security:intercept-url pattern="/drug/*"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />


    <security:logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/login.jsp?logout=success" 
        invalidate-session="true"  />

</security:http>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, actually /drug/* can only be viewed when user has that role i.e. ROLE_DRUG , why i wrote isAuthenticated() with access-denied is because if user is not logged in then they should see login page, and if they are logged in and do not have ROLE_DRUG then they should see /access-denied where i provide a link to buy that role.

Comment: then I think this line should work  <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/accessDenied.jsp">

Answer (score 0):

How about adding this to your configuration, before the intercept-url tag?

```
<access-denied-handler error-page="/drug/access-denied" />
```

Then, you can drop the intercept-url rule for "access-denied"